# python dict unpacking so that kw arguments are added to locals()

Tags: python, dictionary

Quick silly question:

```
def show(**args):
    print(locals())

show(a = 1)
```

I would like the print to show

```
{a: 1}
```

and not

```
{args : {a: 1}}
```

is that possible ?

Comment: Why not `print(args)` then?

Comment: I would like to be able to call the variable inside the function like for instance `b=a**2`, and not b=args.a**2

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately, you can't do what you're asking for.

Python functions use what are called "fast" locals. The compiler assigns each local variable an index into an array, and local assignments and lookups use those indexes, rather than the variable names themselves.

What this means is that you can't add new variable names at runtime. There is no way to write a function that has local variable names that are unknown at compile time, as those variables could not be assigned an index into the fast locals array.

### Code like you want would not be a good idea anyway.

Variable names are intended to be used *by the programmer*, not by the user. If you need a namespace for user-supplied data, use a dictionary where the keys are explicitly data, not local variables.

If you just want to be able to run `b=a**2`, you should make `a` an explicitly named argument for your function, rather than using `**args` in the first place. If you want to require your arguments be passed as keywords (rather than positionally), you can do that with:

```
def show(*, a): # a is a keyword-only argument
    b = a**2
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: Alright thx for the detailed answer - yes i was just a btit lazy and didnt want to rewrite the variable names in the function call. But I gues i need to do it, its fine. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

The same way you would add something to any dictionary.

```
for arg in args:
    locals()[arg] = args[arg]

del args
```

Of course, if there is an `arg` in `args` named "args", then this needs some wonky logic to move "args" to a new unused variable not in `args`:

```
locals()[max(args) + max(locals())] = args
del args

for arg in locals()[max(locals())]:
    locals()[arg] = locals()[max(locals())][arg]

if "arg" in locals()[max(locals())]:
    locals()["arg"] = locals()[max(locals())]["arg"]
else:
    del arg

del locals()[max(locals())]
```

Comment: OK yeah sorry.. I had tried `{locals().update({k,v} for k,v in args,items()}`. I was not sure animore `locals` could be modified like that

Comment: Adding stuff to `locals()` doesn't create new local variables. You're basically just using it as an ordinary dictionary.

Comment: @khelwood the OP didn't say anything about creating new local variables.

Comment: "I would like to be able to call the variable inside the function like for instance b=a**2" the OP said

Comment: @khelwood, if that information is relevant to the question, then it should be in the question.